# Redirect non admin user on specific page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have edited wordpress login redirect for non admin user to the home page with the help of an [article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/customize-login-page/) found via google. But in that article it used function to direct to the home page of site not URL. But I want to redirect on a specific page of my project. The code I have used is

```
function admin_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user )
{
    global $user;
    if( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        if( in_array( "administrator", $user->roles ) ) {
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
add_filter("login_redirect", "admin_login_redirect", 10, 3);
```

How do I redirect to a specific page...

Comment: you can use `get_permalink( page_id )` in place of `home_url()`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it worked perfactly....

Comment: @Shravan Shrama could you please add your comment as an answer so Rishabh can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@James Jones demand here is the solution

you can use `get_permalink( page_id )` in place of `home_url()`